# Homebrew error "kafka: no bottle available!" first error on my m1 macbook

Tags: homebrew, apple-m1

I try to install kafka and zookeeper on my m1 mac book

The brew error occured that " No bottle available!"

`brew Config`

```
HOMEBREW_VERSION: 3.2.14
ORIGIN: https://github.com/Homebrew/brew
HEAD: 4e6919b73444e9f9e02ad81d8afc4bbd97533567
Last commit: 5 days ago
Core tap ORIGIN: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core
Core tap HEAD: 8aa0d34946cf188bebc7b09a919a422036d5c3d9
Core tap last commit: 41 minutes ago
Core tap branch: master
HOMEBREW_PREFIX: /opt/homebrew
HOMEBREW_CASK_OPTS: []
HOMEBREW_MAKE_JOBS: 8
Homebrew Ruby: 2.6.3 => /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/bin/ruby
CPU: octa-core 64-bit arm_firestorm_icestorm
Clang: 12.0.5 build 1205
Git: 2.30.1 => /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/git
Curl: 7.64.1 => /usr/bin/curl
macOS: 11.6-arm64
CLT: 12.5.0.22.11
Xcode: 12.5.1
Rosetta 2: false
```

`brew doctor`

```
Please note that these warnings are just used to help the Homebrew maintainers
with debugging if you file an issue. If everything you use Homebrew for is
working fine: please don't worry or file an issue; just ignore this. Thanks!

Warning: A newer Command Line Tools release is available.
Update them from Software Update in System Preferences or run:
  softwareupdate --all --install --force

If that doesn't show you any updates, run:
  sudo rm -rf /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools
  sudo xcode-select --install

Alternatively, manually download them from:
  https://developer.apple.com/download/more/.
You should download the Command Line Tools for Xcode 13.0.


Warning: Unbrewed header files were found in /usr/local/include.
If you didn't put them there on purpose they could cause problems when
building Homebrew formulae, and may need to be deleted.

Unexpected header files:
  /usr/local/include/bits/stdc++.h

Warning: Homebrew's "sbin" was not found in your PATH but you have installed
formulae that put executables in /opt/homebrew/sbin.
Consider setting your PATH for example like so:
  echo 'export PATH="/opt/homebrew/sbin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc

Warning: Your Xcode (12.5.1) is outdated.
Please update to Xcode 13.0 (or delete it).
Xcode can be updated from the App Store.
```

I already install Jenkins, mysql etc with brew for m1 but this is first error I encounted before.

I already found other cases but It's cause that the brew points wrong repo address.

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/issues/7857
check this site and run command

`brew install -s zookeeper && brew test zookeeper`